# I want to use this query as an arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Can anyone suggest to me how I can convert this query into something that will work in an arrayformula?

```
=iferror(QUERY(importorders!A:H,"Select count(A) where C = 'Thailand Tour' and month(H) = "&MONTH(A3)-1&"and year(H) = "&year(A3)&" label count(A) ''",1),0)
```

It's basically just counting to see how many orders I had in each month.

Thanks for looking.

[View sheet (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOqhW.png)

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Of6cdFYaOzCFwPdZ4ABItD6dghMjHhafRWmDJWaznbg/edit#gid=711075203

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with fake data

Comment: Ok I've created a copy sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Of6cdFYaOzCFwPdZ4ABItD6dghMjHhafRWmDJWaznbg/edit#gid=711075203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, QUERY({importorders!A2:C, 
 EOMONTH(importorders!H2:H, -1)+1},
 "select Col4,count(Col1) 
  where Col3 = 'Thailand Tour' 
    and Col4 is not null 
  group by Col4
  label count(Col1)''", 0), 2, 0), 0))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `group by`

To get just for `Thailand Tour`

```
=iferror(QUERY(importorders!A:H,"Select count(A) where C = 'Thailand Tour' and month(H) = "&MONTH(A3)-1&"and year(H) = "&year(A3)&" group by C label count(A) ''",1),0)
```

To get results for the whole column try this

```
=iferror(QUERY(importorders!A:H,"Select count(A) where month(H) = "&MONTH(A3)-1&"and year(H) = "&year(A3)&" group by C label count(A) ''",1),0)
```

*(A demo sheet with expected results would be really helpful)*

Comment: I am trying to create an arrayfomrula version instead of dragging the formula down. I've made a copy of the doc here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Of6cdFYaOzCFwPdZ4ABItD6dghMjHhafRWmDJWaznbg/edit#gid=711075203